# Wrapping text in export to Excel

Tags: delphi, export-to-excel, word-wrap

Coding in Delphi, I am using Axolot components for Excel export. I need to word-wrap some cells which may contain long strings. Applying the wrap property does not cause the component to resize the row height, however.

My own efforts to resolve the problem have been less than pleasing. As long as the (merged) target cell is fairly wide, and the number of rows needed is small, then I get the proper result. However, if the target cell is relatively narrow, then my height adjustment will be wrong. And what makes it very difficult to understand is that for two different cell widths in the same sheet, using the same string, one will be made higher than needed, by several text rows, and the other will be made not high enough, by a couple of rows.

I have considered getting the actual string width from a canvas, but the component is in a data module, so no canvas is available.

I am using the XLSReadWriteII4 components in Delphi 2007.

Comment: Very nice of you to wait a minute and a half after I posted my answer to add the version information. :-) The solution I posted may still work, however.

Comment: The oversight was unintentional. I've been in a code crunch the last three weeks, and my brain is fuzzy. As I mentioned in reply, however, I am already using the [foWrapText] and it does not adjust row height. The text does wrap, but the row height is my concern in this post.

Comment: You did notice the :-)? I've just downloaded the trial version of v5 (which I've been intending to upgrade to anyway) to evaluate; I'll see if I can help.

Comment: I did. Next time I shall try to reduce the interval. :-)

As to XLSReadWriteII5, we won't be going there. In the move to XE5, we will redesign in FlexCel. But the first release is still a year off, and I would very much like to find a workable solution to this issue for the interim.

Comment: I've added a version that works for XLSRWII 5; I'm not sure what the differences might be between it and 4, but I added it anyway in case it can help someone else at some point.

Comment: I've added another line of code to my XLSRWII2 portion that may help; it's the `AutoHeightRow` call.

Comment: Thanks, I do appreciate the effort. I tried adding AutoHeightRow, and it seems to make no difference. However, if I also add [foShrinkToFit] and do my manual height setting, then apply AutoHeightRow(row), the row is collapsed to single text row height. I suppose that may be a clue. However, removing [foShrinkToFit] makes no difference.

Comment: `foShrinkToFit` would definitely be out of place here, as it directly conflicts with `foWrapText`. It works for me if I use nothing except the code in the code samples I provided, with bot v2 and v5. I don't have v4 available anywhere, so I'm doubtful I'll be able to be of any help here. Even so, can you [edit] to provide a sample of some representative long text, along with the code that adds it, for experimentation?

Answer (score 1):

With XLSReadWriteII2 (as you didn't mention any version), I have these notes for a solution that works for me.

```
// Multiple lines of text in a single cell:
// XLS is an XLSReadWriteII2 component dropped on the form

XLS.Sheets[0].AsString[Col, Row] := 'This is a long text string';
with XLS.Sheets[0].Cell[Col, Row] do
  FormatOptions := FormatOptions + [foWrapText];
XLS.Sheets[0].AutoHeightRow(Row);
```

With XLSReadWriteII5 (the trial version), the following works, and properly sizes the column height to accomodate all of the text within the narrow, default width:

```
XLS.Sheets[0].AsString[Col, Row] := 'This is a long text string';
XLS.Sheets[0].Cell[Col, Row].WrapText := True;
```

Comment: I edited the original to include version info. I am using [foWrapText], but it does not cause the row height to be adjusted to suit. I have therefore coded a routine to determine what height should be sufficient. This routine gives uncertain results.

It would be preferable, of course, to find a way--if there is one--to get the component to adjust the height.

Comment: As I suspected, they have fixed this in XLSReadWriteII5. that property does not exist in XLSReadWriteII4. But thanks for trying.